Playing audio streamed via ws with just_audio in flutter (Mobile)
The aim is to play audio as soon as it comes from the server via the ws connection, and continue playing the whole message without any interruptions. (after the first audio chunk the rest should arrive before the first is done playing)
_handleAudioMessage is called by the WSConnection when it receives an audio message. The audioChunk from that is added to the ConcatenatingAudioSource _audioChunkPlaylist
playQueuedAudio() is called when the user is finished speaking. It aims to loop until the audioChunks arrive from the server and start playing them as they do.
The way I have it set up now, theres a noticeable delay in between some chunks as they are played. I looked around the just_sound source code but couldnt see anything that jumped out as a solution. Would really appreciate any guidance. Feel like I am probably trying to hackily implement something that probably has a conventional way of being done.
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';
import 'package:meddymobile/utils/ws_connection.dart';

class PlayerService {
  final WSConnection _wsConnection;
  final AudioPlayer _audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
  ConcatenatingAudioSource _audioChunkPlaylist =
      ConcatenatingAudioSource(children: []);
  bool _isPlaying = false;

  PlayerService(this._wsConnection) {
    _wsConnection.setHandler('audio_3', _handleAudioMessage);
    _audioPlayer.setAudioSource(_audioChunkPlaylist,
        initialIndex: 0, initialPosition: Duration.zero);
  }

  void _handleAudioMessage(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    if (message['audio'] != null) {
      final audioData = base64Decode(message['audio']);
      _audioChunkPlaylist.add(MyAudioSource(audioData));
    }
  }

  void playQueuedAudio() {
    Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 100), (Timer timer) async {
      if (_isPlaying) return;
      while (_audioChunkPlaylist.length > 0) {
        _isPlaying = true;
        await _audioPlayer.play();
        _audioChunkPlaylist.removeAt(0);
      }
      _isPlaying = false;
    });
  }

  Future<void> stopPlayback() async {
    await _audioPlayer.stop();
    await _audioChunkPlaylist.clear();
    _isPlaying = false;
  }

  Future<void> dispose() async {
    await _audioPlayer.dispose();
  }
}

class MyAudioSource extends StreamAudioSource {
  final List<int> _buffer;

  MyAudioSource(this._buffer);

  @override
  Future<StreamAudioResponse> request([int? start, int? end]) async {
    start ??= 0;
    end ??= _buffer.length;
    return StreamAudioResponse(
      sourceLength: _buffer.length,
      contentLength: end - start,
      offset: start,
      stream: Stream.value(_buffer.sublist(start, end)),
      contentType: 'audio/mp3',
    );
  }
}


did you try StreamAudioSource?

Yes I am using that. However I am making a new StreamAudioSource for every audio chunk. Is there a way to add to the buffer as more audio comes in, and have the new audio be played?
